# antd datepicker allow date 30 days before current and after current 30 days

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, antd

working on react project using ant design datepicker in which I want pick date from current 30 days before and 30 days after and disable the rest of the dates

Anyone help

```
function disabledDate(current) {
  // Can not select days before today and today
  return current+30 && current < moment().endOf('day') ;
}



    <DatePicker
  format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
  disabledDate={disabledDate}
 

/>
```

this code gives current and before that disabled
its using moment

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Thanks but got it with this

```
         <DatePicker
            className="m-0 p-0 pr-2 pl-2  "
            disabledDate={(current) => {                 
              return (
                moment().add(-1, "month") >= current ||
                moment().add(1, "month") <= current
              );
            }}
         />
```

Comment: Yes, that is what i ment, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the arg `current` is number and you are comparing it to `moment().endOf('day')` which is `object`.

Start from there, because for any number that you try to compare to this `object` will return `true`, e.g.

```
-1 < moment().endOf("day") => true
0 < moment().endOf("day") => true
1 < moment().endOf("day") => true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
  <DatePicker format={'YYYY-MM-DD'}
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
            disabledDate={current =>
              !current ||
              current.isAfter(moment().add(30, 'days')) ||
              current.isSameOrBefore(moment().subtract(30, 'days'))
            }
          />
```

Hope it will help you cheers!